# Swift Firebase: UIRefreshControl with .childAdded

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase

Ok, pls pardon me if this might be a very elementary question, but how do I refresh my tableView with only new items added to Firebase?

I am trying to implement a 'pull to refresh' for my tableView and populate my tableView with new items that have been added to Firebase. At viewDidLoad, I call .observeSingleEvent(.value) to display the table.

At the refresh function, I call .observe(.childAdded). However doing so will make the app consistently listen for things added, making my app consistently reloadingData. How do I code it such that it only refreshes when I do the 'pull to refresh'? My code so far:

```
lazy var refresh: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refresh = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 20, height: 20))
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
        return refresh
    }()

var eventsArray: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("events").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                self.eventsArray.insert(snap as! FIRDataSnapshot, at: 0)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }

    func refreshData() {
        self.eventsArray = []

        ref.child("events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            self.eventsArray.insert(snapshot, at: 0)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.refresh.endRefreshing()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
```

I also attempted observeSingleEvent(.childAdded) but it only pulls out one single entry (the very top entry) from Firebase.

I am not sure if my approach is correct in the first place. Any advice here pls, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
var lastKey: String? = nil
```

In the loop where you iterate over the children set the lastKey to the current snap's key.

```
lastKey = snap.key
```

Let me know if this works for you.

```
func refreshData() {
    // Make sure you write a check to make sure lastKey isn't nil
    ref.child("events").orderByKey().startAt(lastKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // You'll have to get rid of the first childsince it'll be a duplicate, I'm sure you can figure that out.
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            self.eventsArray.insert(snap as! FIRDataSnapshot, at: 0)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.refresh.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

Comment: hi there, although the above method works, it may not be sustainable in the long term. If users were to delete events and it turns out that the laskKey gets deleted, it would cause the app to crash. Is there a better way to resolve this?

Comment: Does it cause the app to crash? I'm fairly certain it would just either not return any results, or simply skip that key, I might be wrong though. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes it does, I just tested it. But I managed to resolve it as it crashed at the line which I attempted to remove the duplicate child. That being said, it still causes the app to not display the latest set of events, ie comparing the database to the tableView. Users can delete and create events, so rightfully the database could be very dynamic. Seems like recreating the whole tableView could be a more sustainable solution?

Comment: Granted but then couldn't you just use the method you used in your viewDidLoad() and simply reuse that every time you 'refresh'?